# computed property doesn't print out the update I need it to do so

Tags: vue.js

I created a computed property that is an array of values and created a 
   scroll-monitor 
   responsible for updating the property by adding more values however what I 
   noticed is that
   Information gets updated in the dom but it doesn't update in the page.
   I really don't know why

```
   <!-- myCode -->
   <template>
     <div class="u"  >
        <div class="makeit" v-for="search in Searched" > 
            <img :src=' "Images/Houses/" + search.image'   width="200px" 
               class="xz" />
        </div>
    </div>
       <div id="mmm" class="Mola" > More results</div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
       export default{
        computed :{
           Searched(){
                return this.$store.state.Searched.slice(0,8);
                    }
                },
       methods:{ 
            done(){
             if(this.Searched.length < this.$store.state.Searched.length){
        let added= this.$store.state.Searched
        .slice(this.Searched.length,this.Searched.length+8);
         added.map(added=>this.Searched.push(added));
                                                         }
                 },
        mounted(){
            var g = this;
            var y = document.getElementById("mmm");
            var e = scrollMonitor.create(y);
            e.enterViewport(()=>{
            g.done()
                            });
                 }
                 }
       </script>
```

Comment: You're pushing onto the end of a computed that only returns the first 8 elements and has no setter.

Comment: I thought there is a way leaving it this way but I will then change the code to include the setter this way. anyway thanks for the help